# How to use this execute immediate create table to insert values in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using execute immediate to create table and use this table into my code to insert some values when i run this code .it gives me error that table and view does not exist.why?. this code has ability to create table because when i use drop and create table command with existing table by using execute immediate then my code works fine and when i just remove drop table syntax, my code does not work, Please help me to clear my concept about dynamic SQL-----------

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  ddl_table VARCHAR2(200);
  r_emp     SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST   := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
  v_array   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('ACCT_ID',
                                                         'PARENT_ACCT_ID',
                                                         'CUST_ID',
                                                         'ACCT_NAME',
                                                         'BILLING_CYCLE_TYPE',
                                                         'PAID_FLAG',
                                                         'BILL_DELIVER_METHOD');
BEGIN
  ddl_table := 'CREATE TABLE test123(
                                      v_column VARCHAR2(50),
                                      v_count  NUMBER
                                    )';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl_table;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_array.COUNT LOOP
    r_emp.EXTEND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM account_profile 
                        WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(' ||v_array(i) || ',''[A-Za-z0-9.]'')'
      INTO r_emp(i);

    IF r_emp(i) <> 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_array(i) || ': ' || r_emp(i));
      INSERT INTO test123 VALUES (v_array(i), r_emp(i));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error report -

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 24, column 17:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the anonymous block is pre-validated (pre-compiled) before it is valid. Oracle will check all objects in use before executing it. Since you are creating `test123` dynamically it doesn't exist so your insert statement fails.

You can instead, use an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command to also insert the data on your `test123` table.

The way you use the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for an insert command is either concatenating the parameters or preparing them, I prefer the later. Like this

```
execute immediate 'insert into test123 values (:param1,:param2)' using v_array(i), r_emp(i);
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm#:%7E:text=The%20EXECUTE%20IMMEDIATE%20statement%20executes,and%20so%20on%20in%20advance.) for the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command.

Though it shows how it works and explain the usage of it, it doesn't particularly answer you direct question on the comments.
So

> can you explain :param1,:param2

Those are called "binding" parameters that will be replaced by the variables used after the `using` statement. It doesn't matter their  name only the order in which they appear on the string. The number of parameters within the dynamic string needs to match the number of parameters after the `using` statement.

> why we use it with : colon and what are these

The colon `:` there is just to make it easier for the parser to know what to replace and where when using the variables you provided after the `using` statement

Translating that execute immediate it would be something like this:

`... values (:param1,:param2)' using v_array(i), r_emp(i)`

Hey "execute immediate" whenever you see `:param1` please replace it with the content of the variable I'm providing as `v_array(i)` and whenever you see `:param2` please replace it with the content of the variable I'm providing as `r_emp(i)`

Comment: but how can i use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command to insert values in my code and i am using both collection v_array(i) and r_emp(i) with execute immediate command inside the loop . I used Like this  --Execute immediate 'insert into test123 values (v_array(i),r_emp(i))'; --- but it gives me below error . Error report -.
ORA-00904: "R_EMP": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 80      ------ can you plz write this for me

Comment: I've add an edit to show how to use the parameters on your execute immediate command.

Comment: Thanks a lot jorge , you are the best. but plz can you explain :param1,:param2 why we use it with  : colon and what are these ?

Comment: Sure I will add the link to the official documentation, I think it will be better than me explaining it. And also if this answer is ok to you please consider marking it as accepted. It is the V icon to the right of it :)